# Set docker toolbox container to receive information sended to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I have a prototype that sends information to the host machine, and with **Docker for Windows**, the container grabs that information and everything works fine.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  middleware:
    container_name: middleware
    image: hyperloopupv:middleware
    build: './receta' 
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
    - "1338:1338/udp"
    - "5556:5556/udp"
```

But others from my team are using **Docker Toolbox**, and Docker Toolbox can not use localhost. I have tried to send the information from the prototype to the IP of the container(192.168.99.100), but the packets are lost.

Is there a way, that my team(using Docker Toolbox) and I(using Docker for Windows) can get this running without problems with the same compose file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Desktop and Toolbox are completely different products. Docker Desktop runs on Hyper-V, Docker Toolbox on Virtualbox. Desktop is the actual product, Toolbox is the “legacy desktop solution”.

It is possible to manipulate its IP address. If you look a the docs under ‘Options’ you find an option called virtualbox-hostonly-cidr that you can use to manipulate the IP address when you create a new machine. But before you try this notice that it is called ‘hostonly’. This means it uses the Virtualbox Host-Only adapter and “the virtual machines cannot talk to the world outside the host since they are not connected to a physical networking interface” (from the Virtualbox docs).

So unfortunately it seems there is no simple solution to your problem.